# Unit Test useFetch Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library, react-custom-hooks

I am getting an `Object.dispatchError` when I run my unit test for my custom `useFetch` hook.

The hook:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const useFetch = (url) => {

  const [data, setData] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);

    const apiCall = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(url);
        if (!res.ok) throw new Error(`Error - ${res.status}`);
        const json = await res.json();

        setData(json);
        setError(null);
      } catch (err) {
        setError(`useFetch Error!`);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    apiCall();
  }, [url]);

  return { data, loading, error };
};

export default useFetch;
```

My unit test:

```
  import { renderHook, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
  import useFetch from './useFetch';

  it('Should handle no URL provided', async () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useFetch());

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(result.current.error).toBe("useFetch Error!");
    });
  });
```

The error:

```
console.error
Error: AggregateError
  at Object.dispatchError (jsdom\living\xhr\xhr-utils.js:63:19)
  at Request.<anonymous> (jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xhr\XMLHttpRequest-impl.js:655:18)
  at Request.emit (node:events:531:35)
  at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\helpers\http-request.js:121:14)
  at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:519:28)
  at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:492:9)
  at Socket.emit (node:events:519:28)
  at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
  at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) undefined
```

Maybe it is my `waitFor()` in the unit test that is not written correctly?
How should I unit test my custom hook?

Cheers!

StackBlitz: [useFetch Custom Hook](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-nnsfq2?file=src%2Fhooks%2FuseFetch.js)

(Although, how you can run unit tests in stackblitz is beyond me...)

Answer (score 2):

You've not provided a `URL` to your `useFetch` hook, so it's trying to make a request to an undefined URL. The error you're getting is related to the request itself, not the error handling within your hook.

One way would be to mock the `fetch` function to avoid making actual requests and simulate different scenarios for your hook. Something like:

```js
// ...your imports

// Mock the fetch function
global.fetch = jest.fn(() =>
  Promise.resolve({
    ok: true,
    json: () => Promise.resolve({}),
  })
);
// other tests...

it('Should handle no URL provided', async () => {
  // Clear any previous mock calls
  fetch.mockClear();

  // Set the fetch mock to reject with an error
  fetch.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.reject('Failed to fetch'));

  const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(() => useFetch(undefined));

  // waited for error to happen here
  await waitFor(() => result.current.error !== '');

  expect(result.current.error).toBe("useFetch Error!");
});
```

---

**Sidenote:** You can also leverage the *[msw](https://mswjs.io/)*  package to write more accurate unit tests for APIs without resorting to manual mocking. MSW uses *[service workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API)* behind the scenes to intercept API requests and inject test data before making the actual calls.

Comment: I import {waitForNextUpdate } from "@testing-library/react"; but then I get an error saying wrap it in act(). When I import and use act it says waitForNextUpdate is not a function.

Comment: @ScottishSmile I have updated my answer, please try this once.

Comment: Thanks for trying but it is not working. There is no error, but the test is failing. Expected: "useFetch Error!"  Received: ""

Comment: @ScottishSmile is it possible to replicate it on some online compiler like https://stackblitz.com/? I'll try to help you out here. This should be achievable easily if you provide some way to replicate it

Comment: I have added a stackblitz that demos the useFetch hook. I have no idea how to get the unit tests working in stackblitz though. ..

Comment: I raised this to see if anyone knows how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78051063/react-unit-tests-on-stackblitz